# Exception is never thrown in the corresponding try block

Tags: java, exception, testing, junit

I have this method:

```
public int addInt(int x, int y){
    try{
        if(x<1 || y<1){
            throw new InvalidValueExeption();
        }
    } catch(InvalidValueExeption i){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    return x+y;
}
```

`InvalidValueExeption` is a custom exception. So I wanted to test this:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    AddClass a = new AddClass();
    boolean thrown = false;

    try{
        a.addInt(-2, 3);
    } catch(InvalidValueException e){
        thrown=true;
    }

    assertTrue(thrown);
}
```

I can't run this test, because it says `Exception exception.InvalidValueException is never thrown in the corresponding try block`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How can `addInt` method throw the `InvalidValueException` exception if you are catching this exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `addInt()` method doesn't throw `InvalidValueException` (*). Inside the method, you do throw it, but you catch it before it can "leave" your method. So, for the outside world, there is no `InvalidValueException` coming from your method.

Then, correctly the compiler tells you that there's no point in catching the `InvalidValueException`.

So, instead of immediately catching the exception inside your method, declare the method to throw `InvalidValueException`:

```
public int addInt(int x, int y) throws InvalidValueException {
    if (x < 1 || y < 1) {
        throw new InvalidValueException();
    }
    return x + y;
}
```

**Rationale:**

Exceptions are meant to tell the caller (**) of some method that it couldn't fulfill its task, i.e. your `addInt()` method is designed to add only positive numbers. And if someone tries it with a number below 1, the method answers with the exception instead of returning a value, thus saying: "Hey, something went wrong, so I can't give you an answer (and the problem description is [the exception with its message and so on])."

---

( * ) I assume, the missing "c" is just a typo, and you don't have two different exception classes.

( ** ) That's important. I'm not talking about `System.out.println()`, as that's telling something to the **user**, not the **caller**.

Answer (score 1):

If `InvalidValueExeption` is a checked exception then the compiler will complain because `addInt` is not declared to *throw*  `InvalidValueExeption`.

If `InvalidValueExeption` is not a checked exception then the test will fail because `addInt` swallows the `InvalidValueExeption`.

There's also a possible typo in your question: `addInt()` throws `InvalidValueExeption` whereas `test()` tries to catch `InvalidValueException`. In the former case exception is spelled "Exeption", in the latter case it is spelled "Exception", note the missing "c".

The following approach will work:

```
public int addInt(int x, int y) {
    if (x < 1 || y < 1) {
        throw new InvalidValueException();
    }

    return x + y;
}

@Test(expected = InvalidValueException.class)
public void test(){
    AddClass a = new AddClass();

    a.addInt(-2, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of i think your `InvalidValueExeption` is a subtype of [RuntimeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html).

> RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions.
>   Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method or
>   constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of
>   the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or
>   constructor boundary.

So if you need to indicate that you throw an InvalidValueExeption or inherit `Exception` instead.

Here the exception is declared on your method and thrown :

```
public int addInt(int x, int y) throws InvalidValueExeption  {
     try {
        //..
         throw new InvalidValueExeption();
     } catch (InvalidValueExeption e) {
         // do some logging the throw back at you
         throw e;
     }
}
```